# How should we manage Magento 2 tags?

Tags: discussion, magento2

Since questions about Magento 2 are popping up lately, I think we need a way to organize the tags for them.
I don't think a tag [magento2-pre-alpha](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-pre-alpha) is enough. Like @Dan [says here](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/a/80/146)

> Features in it can change daily, stuff removed, stuff added. It is
>   very likely that questions that would be asked about "How can this be
>   done", "How is this implemented" etc... would have different answers
>   once the full version is released.

and I agree.
If you take a look at versions 2.0.0.0-dev45 and 2.0.0.0.-dev46 you can see huge differences.
Almost any answer for questions pre-dev46 may now have close to 0 value.
I suggest that beside the [magento2-pre-alpha](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-pre-alpha) tag we should also add tags with the versions: [2.0.0.0-dev46](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2.0.0.0-dev46).
Waiting for other opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm in favor of the dev* number because it's very clear what version the answer applies to. We should take care to prod the OPs for the version when answering Magento 2 questions.

Answer (score 0):

We should orient on the answers, too.

Some question may be old, and the answers for way newer dev versions, so we should add tags for them to.

Anyway, the -pre-alpha tag should get added to every magento2 question for now